# Import .tar file using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, tar, azure-data-factory

How do I import a TAR file using Azure Data Factory and unzip (decompress) them into Azure Data lake store. I could find it possible for .gZ and .zip files but not .tar!

Just FYI, my .tar file sits in the on-premise file system.

Request your kind help.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a .NET custom activity to install the tar.exe command (that you will have uploaded to Blob store) and run it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-use-custom-activities

You can adapt the following code (that runs RScript.exe):
https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/blob/master/Samples/RunRScriptUsingADFSample/InvokeRScript.cs

Comment: Hi Alexandre, Can I not have any built-in ADF property to decompress the .tar files? I really don't want to go with .NET custom activity. Do you have any idea on Map Reduce activity solving this issue?

Comment: Yes, a general-purpose Map Reduce activity to run a command line is available at https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/tree/master/Samples/CustomizedJavaOnHDInsight