# copy and decompress .tar file with Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I m trying to copy and decompress .tar file from FTP to Azure Data Lake Store.
.tar file contains HTML files. In the copy activity, on a dataset, i select Compression type GZipDeflate, but I wonder what file format do I need to use? Is it supported to do such I thing without custom activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So its true that there is no way just to decompress .tar files with ADF or ADL Analytics, but there is an option to take a content from every file in .tar file and save as an output in U-SQL. 
I have a scenario that I need to take content from html files inside the .tar file, so i just created html extractor that will take stream content of each html file in .tar file and save in a U-SQL output variable.
Maybe this can help someone who has a similar use case.
I used SharpCompress.dll for extracting and looping over .tar files in c#.

Comment: Having a data lake store doesn't mean you have data lake analytics to use u-sql, you never pointed that on your original question so I didn't even considered it.

Comment: yes my main question was is that possible with ADF. 
This is just small updated, maybe can help someone. 
Sorry Martin.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Data factory doesn't support decompression of .tar files. The supported types for ftp are GZip, Deflate, BZip2, and ZipDeflate. (as seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#compression-support).

A solution may be to save the files in one of the supported formats, or try a custom activity as was explained here, although I'm not sure if it was for data factory v1 or v2: [Import .tar file using Azure Data Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41949630/import-tar-file-using-azure-data-factory)

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks Martin, as i thought. :)