# Compose to tar file in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

my source is sql db ,sink in Blob storage. I need to create Tar file on sink side(blob storage).

i have chosen tar as compression type and optimal as level of compression but throwing error as shown.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylw41.png)
But when i tried for ZIPflate its working but requirement is compress to tar in output can any one help me.

Comment: Please share any relevant code by editing your Question - [instead of a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Fewer people are likely to reproduce your issue without having your code in a copyable form.

Answer (score 1):

As per this official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#compression-support+) only below file formats and compression codecs are supported by copy activity in Azure Data Factory.

Azure Data Factory supports the following file formats.

- Avro format
- Binary format
- Delimited text format
- Excel format
- JSON format
- ORC format
- Parquet format
- XML format

Regarding .tar compression refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49281426) Stackoverflow answer by [DraganB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7593775/draganb)